# Confirm and Cancellation one button

Tags: naming

We are developing a carpool app. Below is the search results of people closeby who are willing to carpool. Obviously we need to show the name, location. The person offering needs to also `Confirm` a closeby dude. Also after confirmation there should be a `Cancellation` option.

Questions

1. Is there a better way to represent the `call the dude` instead of a button (too many buttons)
2. Is there a way to combine the confirm and cancel button ?

I dont want to use icons at all. Its tough to get icons to resize properly across the 3000 android devices.

Any best practices here ?

[image][image]

Comment: Confirm and cancellation one button? Sounds like using one work to mean both "yes" and "no". I have no idea how that would work!

Comment: Well, if you confirm, you can cancel, and if your cancel you can confirm. So its like a toggle. Many have that look and feel these days. `Airline mode is off, press to On`

Comment: I see where you are getting to but I would not use those terms that way. A "confirmation" does convey a certain commitment and finality. "Cancel" conveys an absence of commitment. Instead of "Confirm and Cancel" how about "Accept and Cancel"? If I make a reservation at a restaurant and the restaurant gives me a "confirmation" of my reservation, I will be pretty upset if they afterwards "cancel" it.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained what you mean by "cancel". What page of the app is this? Do you search for available carpools, see a list, then choose one and get this page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icons are important, you shouldn't avoid using them simply because you have issues resizing them for different devices.

All your icon resize problems will be solved if you use vector icons like the ones available from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/).

Comment: Good idea to use text instead of images. And great link!

Comment: I wonder if I can use vector icons in android ?

Comment: @Siddharth The ones I link to are just a font, so if you can use normal text fonts then you can use an icon font too.

Comment: I guess so, I'll try it out. I'll wait for other answers as well for a while. Thanks.

Comment: @Siddharth Yeh, it's good to see what else people come up with :)

Comment: Why the downvote for this answer?

Comment: @Mishax yeh, it would be useful if the person also gave me feedback so I can learn from it :)